# How can I read write this array of structure from/to a file?

Tags: c

I have used an array of struct to store the user's details. How can I store initialized values in a file (to read), and then perform operations and update the modified values back to the same file?

```
struct User {
   char userName[10];
   char password[10];
   float accountBalance;
   unsigned int accountNumber;  
}user[MAX_LIMIT]= {
        {"admin","admin123",10000},
        {"pankaj","abc",5000},
        {"sweety","def",980},
        {"raani","qwe",4000},
    };
```

Comment: `fwrite` and `fread`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing an array of structs to a binary file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368677/writing-an-array-of-structs-to-a-binary-file-in-c)

Comment: That which you label as "Code:" and format as code.. if it really is code, then what programming language is it? Please use this info https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and [edit] to make you post less confusing.

Comment: Should the file format be binary or text? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: any format.. @Jabberwocky